# react-flexbox-grid gives error in testing in node_modules how to solve it

Tags: testing, webpack, enzyme

I'm using react 16.6.3, react-flexbox-grid 2.1.2 and webpack version 4.25.1  and for test cases jest 23.6 and enzyme. While running my tests I get the following error:

```
/home/sanju/Quizetencyplayground/quizetencyplatform/webapp/node_modules/flexboxgrid2/flexboxgrid2.css:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.container {
                                                                                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-flexbox-grid/lib/classNames.js:8:20)
```

can anyone tell me solution why it is how to remove this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Webpack doesn't know how to handle CSS files.

You probably have to add a CSS loader like [this one](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader).

---

If it is an option for you I would suggest to use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/) so you don't have to configure Webpack.

Comment: I have css loader in webpack common config and external css file also  working fine ---------

Comment: Then I guess jest doesn't know what to do with CSS files. See if this issue helps https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3094